# How can i verify toast messages using Selendroid

Tags: android, testing, automation, selendroid

I have tried to verify toast in selendroid Automation using `partialLinkText` as follows:

```
private boolean getToast(String text) {
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3); 
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.
     presenceOfElementLocated(By.partialLinkText(text)));
   return true;
}
```

and even i have tried `waitForElement` too.

```
 waitForElement(By.partialLinkText(text), 14, driver);
```

but in both cases the test failed with `NoSuchElementException`. is selendroid support toasts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
waitForElement(By.partialLinkText("Your Toast message"), 4, driver);
```

Where first parameter is your toast message. Second parameter is Time duration in Seconds,third is driver.

Comment: ya i have tried and it is already given in question. in both scenario i am getting NoSuchElementException